# What am I doing wrong to show the sequence with psmatrix?

Tags: psmatrix

Don´t appear the lines in the last lines of code to show the sequence!!1

(edited after Crishtopher suggestion/comment)

What I want is(marked in red): 
[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}


%\input{pssettings.tex}
\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90}‎
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.9cm,colsep=0.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    &
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,blur,shadow](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \rput(0,-1.35){Solución Actual}
    \\
       &
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.55,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput(0,-1.35){Generar Vecindad}
    \\

    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=0.09,opacity=0.3]{-}(0.40,0.40)(0.90,-0.10)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=0.09,opacity=0.3]{-}(0.40,-0.10)(0.90,0.40)

    %\psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
     &
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput(0,-1.35){Elegir el Mejor Vecino}
    \\

\psdiabox[shadow=true,framesep=0.1]{\tabular{c}Criterio de\\ Aspiración\endtabular}
    &\psdiabox[shadow=true]{\tabular{c}Está en\\ Lista Tabú?\endtabular}\\
    &
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \rput(0,-1.35){\tabular{c}Aceptarla como nueva solución\\y comenzar de nuevo el proceso\endtabular}
    \\


       %Links
 %   \ncline{->}{1,2}{2,2}
  % \ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2}
   % \ncline{->}{4,2}{5,2}^{\textcolor{red}{No}}
%    \ncline{->}{4,2}{5,1}<{\textcolor{red}{Si}}
 %   \ncline{->}{4,1}{5,2}<{\textcolor{red}{Si}}
  %  \ncline{->}{4,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{No}}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

I think that after reach the final of this diagram, I return to pencil and paper :-)) It´s so complicated, reach what you want if you are not expert!!

Comment: It is hard to say what goes wrong -- I have no idea what you have in mind, how the diagram should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that initially you had empty lines (due to some `\\~`) and your forget these were nevertheless numbered. Whence the interest of giving names to actual nodes.

Anyway here two solutions, using (partly) either `\oval` or `frame` boxes. I give both codes, which are essentially the same, with here and there different parameters/settings and commands.

**With oval boxes:**

```
  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[textwidth = 18cm, textheight = 25cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1
\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1

\usepackage{pstricks}%[pdf]
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%\resizebox{18cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize


\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\psset[pst-node]{mcol = l}}


\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.2, colsep=-1.25]% defines the distance between two frames
%
 & [name = SA]
  \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Solución Actual}&
    \\[1.25cm]
%
    & [name=GV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)%
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.55,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Generar Vecindad}
    \\[0.25cm]
    %~\\
   & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=0.1,name = Vvacia]%
    \rule{0.8cm}{0pt}\clap{\begin{tabular}{c}¿Vecindad=$∅$?\end{tabular}}\rule[-0.21cm]{0pt}{0.6cm}\rule{0.8cm}{0pt}%{}\psdiamond(1.6,1.4)
   & [mnode = oval, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.22,name = Vfin]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hskip\itemsep}l@{}}\textbullet &\upstrut{4ex} Finalizar \\ \textbullet & Eligir Mejor\\ &Solución Visitada\negstrut{3ex} \end{tabular}
    \\[-0.35cm]
%
  [name=Wr]
   \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=0.09,opacity=0.3}
    \psline(0.40,0.40)(0.90,-0.10)
    \psline(0.40,-0.10)(0.90,0.40)
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Eliminar Vecino Elegido}
%
     & [name=EMV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Elegir Mejor Vecino}
    &
    \\[0.5cm]
%
    [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = CA]
    \begin{tabular}{c}¿Verifica\\Criterio de\\Aspiración?\end{tabular}
        & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = LT]
    \rule{1cm}{0pt}\clap{\begin{tabular}{c}¿Está en\\Lista Tabú? \end{tabular}}\rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm}\rule{1cm}{0pt}
    \\
%
    & [name=Ace, mnode = r]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
     &
    \\
%
    &    [mnode = oval, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.22,name = Repetir]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hskip\itemsep}p{7cm}@{}} %>{}
     \textbullet\upstrut{4ex} & Actualizar Lista Tabú\\
     \textbullet & Aceptar Vecino Elegido como nueva solución\\
     \textbullet & Repetir proceso hasta alcanzar el máximo de iteraciones.\\
      \textbullet & Si se han agotado la iteraciones, tomar como Solución, la mejor de todas las visitadas \negstrut{2ex}
     \end{tabular}
%}%
\end{psmatrix}
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos=0.45}
\ncline{LT}{CA}_{Si}
{\psset{nodesepB = 1.20}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.65cm]{SA}{GV}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 7pt, nodesepB = 1.15]{Vvacia}{EMV}^{No}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 7pt, nodesepB = 1.15]{LT}{Ace}^{No}%
 \ncline[nodesepB = 1.65cm]{CA}{Wr}^{No}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 7pt, angleA = -90]{CA}{Ace}\nbput{Si}}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.67cm]{EMV}{LT}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.65cm]{GV}{Vvacia}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 1.25, angleA = 90]{Wr}{Vvacia}
 \ncline{Vvacia}{Vfin}^{Si} %[nodesepA = 0.1cm]
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.25cm]{Ace}{Repetir}
%}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**With frame boxes:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[textwidth = 18cm, textheight = 25cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1
\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1

\usepackage{pstricks}%[pdf]
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%\resizebox{18cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize


\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\psset[pst-node]{mcol = l}}


\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.2, colsep=-0.8]% defines the distance between two frames
%
 & [name = SA]
  \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Solución Actual}&
    \\[1.25cm]
%
    & [name=GV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)%
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.55,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Generar Vecindad}
    \\[0.5cm]
%
   & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=0.1,name = Vvacia]%
    \rule{0.8cm}{0pt}\clap{\begin{tabular}{c}¿Vecindad=$∅$?\end{tabular}}\rule[-0.21cm]{0pt}{0.6cm}\rule{0.8cm}{0pt}%{}\psdiamond(1.6,1.4)
   & [mnode = r, name = Vfin]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.15]{\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip\itemsep}l}
    \textbullet & Finalizar \\ \textbullet & Eligir Mejor\\ &Solución Visitada
    \end{tabular}}
    \\
%
  [name=Wr]
   \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=0.09,opacity=0.3}
    \psline(0.40,0.40)(0.90,-0.10)
    \psline(0.40,-0.10)(0.90,0.40)
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Eliminar Vecino Elegido}
%
     & [name=EMV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Elegir Mejor Vecino}
    &
    \\[0.5cm]
%
    [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = CA]
    \begin{tabular}{c}¿Verifica\\Criterio de\\Aspiración?\end{tabular}
        & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = LT]
    \rule{1cm}{0pt}\clap{\begin{tabular}{c}¿Está en\\Lista Tabú? \end{tabular}}\rule[-0.45cm]{0pt}{1cm}\rule{1cm}{0pt}
    \\
%
    & [name=Ace, mnode = r]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
     &
    \\
%
    &    [mnode =r, name = Repetir]%
    \psframebox[shadow=true,framearc = 0.15,]{\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip\itemsep}p{7cm}} %
     \textbullet & Actualizar Lista Tabú\\
     \textbullet & Aceptar Vecino Elegido como nueva solución\\
     \textbullet & Repetir proceso hasta alcanzar el máximo de iteraciones.\\
      \textbullet & Si se han agotado la iteraciones, tomar como Solución, la mejor de todas las visitadas
     \end{tabular}}
%}%
\end{psmatrix}
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4}
\ncline{LT}{CA}_{Si}
{\psset{nodesepB = 1.20}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.65cm]{SA}{GV}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 7pt, nodesepB = 1.15]{Vvacia}{EMV}^{No}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 7pt, nodesepB = 1.15]{LT}{Ace}^{No}%
 \ncline[nodesepB = 1.65cm]{CA}{Wr}^{No}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 7pt, angleA = -90]{CA}{Ace}\nbput[npos =0.4]{Si}}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.67cm]{EMV}{LT}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.65cm]{GV}{Vvacia}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 1.25, angleA = 90]{Wr}{Vvacia}
 \ncline{Vvacia}{Vfin}^{Si} %[nodesepA = 0.1cm]
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.25cm]{Ace}{Repetir}
%}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT!!! :-)   one question Why there are so sep between cols, if colsep=0.8 only?? If I change to 0.1 the separation in the graph is still the same as the col winth colsep=0.8   ¿¿?¿?

I like very much your work!!! :-)

Comment: supose taht  I want to reduce this image, to the 80% of its size, ¿What comands and where I have to insert?. I view once in a herberts job, but... II try and try, and have no good results making by my own hands

Comment: For the first question: there should be a change, but betwwen column 1 and column 2, it must be hard to see  , because of the `\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2cm}` command which inserts a horizontal space of 2 cm at the beginning of every entry of column 2 — which is the same as increasing colsep by 2 cm vetween column 1 and column2/ If you find it's too much, change it.

Comment: For the second question, it is enough to add at the very beginning `unit=0.8cm` to the series of `\psset{…}` (remember the default is 1 cm). Do not scale the figure: it will also scale the font.

Comment: I´m impressed for your high level, and Herbert´s level. It´s amazing!!, simply... amazing!

Comment: @Mika Ike: Thank you for the compliment, but please don't compare me with Herbert. He knows so much more than me. I've just been using pstricks for more than 15 years, so I've become fussy — just as (La)TeX makes you fussy about typography..

Comment: I modify a little things based on your job. and I want to put finally (the modifications is in PINK) as http://sensa.square7.ch/gfhdfhghjghjf4.jpg add a framebox onn the END ITEMS (if possible, if not... leaving so)  I was trying thing but I can´t found the option to mnode to do a FRAME (yes for circle,oval,...) and I have any problem with the arrow between 2nd and 3rd cols. I let here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax3axw03kwuz62g/proba017.tex   my code (based on you) . I love the style of that graph. When I finish, It will be my base diagrams ;-)

Comment: I like that in psset of mnode=dia  or circle or... I can adjust framesep= with negative numbers to adjust more an more close to the text. For example the diag in this examples, with framesep=-0.2 is fantastic adjust!  :-)))) I´m happy  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6Sxv-sUYtM&feature=kp    (please, excuse me for the joke :-) )

Comment: Any questions about the last version osf this diagram...if you can... http://sensa.square7.ch/diagramsnap0fd7.jpg

Comment: @Mika Ikke: I've updated my answer, with both variants (oval boxes ans frame boxes). Is that what you want?

Comment: PERFECT! :-) SOLVED PERFECTLY! I´m viewing your code in detail to understand things and made a base for diagrams. I´m very gratefull to you. I think that you can put this post as a good reference to do diagrams.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14036/discussion-between-bernard-and-mika-ike)